# How to uninstall (totally remove) tonido from Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04

I recently installed **Tonido** in Ubuntu ,but It is not starting How to uninstall it?I followed these steps to install

```
sudo mkdir /usr/local/tonido  
cd /usr/local/tonido  
sudo wget http://www.tonido.com/download.php?tonido64.tar.gz  
mv download.php\?tonido64.tar.gz tonido64.tar.gz  
sudo tar -zxvf tonido64.tar.gz  
./tonido.sh start
```

from this [website](http://www.tonido.com/tonidodesktop_downloads/)

Comment: [Edit] your question and add how you installed it, and what Tonido might be.

Comment: `sudo apt-get remove tonido`

Comment: "E: Unable to locate package tonido "  this is the output @Liso

Comment: @Liso there is no deb package to uninstall. Why should your command work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't installed the application, only downloaded via `wget`and extracted via `tar` and the script `./tonido.sh start` installs nothing.

Therefore there is nothing to uninstall.

You could remove the misplaced archive in `/usr/local/tonido`.

```
sudo rm /usr/local/tonido/tonido64.tar.gz
```

and the extracted content. The archive doesn't contains a parent folder for `tonido`, therefore we can't delete a folder.

Remove the extracted files via

```
sudo tar tf tonido64.tar.gz | sudo xargs rm -r 2>/dev/null
```

---

Ok, I see now, you have created a folder `/usr/local/tonido`. You could also simply remove the folder `/usr/local/tonido`

```
sudo rm -r /usr/local/tonido
```

Comment: folder deleted @A.B,but how to install it correctly so that it start properly

Comment: Sorry, that should be a new question. Comments are not the right place to answer new questions. :)

Answer (score 0):

Uninstalling Tonido has two steps in Linux.

1. Delete Tonido executables and library (typically in `/usr/local/tonido` folder (Tonido could also be installed in other location by the user during installation).
2. Delete all local data stored by Tonido and Profile by deleting

   ```
   rm -rf ~/tonido
   ```

Comment: Both not working @Prabim....

Comment: And what isn't working?