# How to install Tonido in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04

I recently installed Tonido in Ubuntu but it is not starting,so I removed it by the help of [ask ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/663988/how-to-uninstall-totally-remove-tonido-from-ubuntu-14-04/664007?noredirect=1#comment957565_664007) Now how to install it properly?

Comment: how did you install it? Are you using 32-bit or 64-bit system? What commands did you run? What do you mean by 'not starting'?

Comment: @Ron I'm using 64-bit

Answer (score 0):

If you are using 64-bit:

```
sudo mkdir /usr/local/tonido
cd /usr/local/tonido
sudo wget http://www.tonido.com/download.php?tonido64.tar.gz
sudo mv download.php\?tonido64.tar.gz tonido64.tar.gz
sudo tar -zxvf tonido64.tar.gz
./tonido.sh start
```

After running, open your internet browser and go to `http://127.0.0.1:10001`

If you are using [32-bit](http://www.tonido.com/support/display/docs/Ubuntu+Linux+32+bit):

```
wget http://www.tonido.com/download.php?TonidoSetup_i686.deb
mv download.php\?TonidoSetup_i686.deb TonidoSetup_i686.deb
apt-get install fontconfig
dpkg -i TonidoSetup_i686.deb
#for GTK tray app, run: 
/usr/local/tonido/tonidostart.sh 
#for normal daemon app, run:
/usr/local/tonido/tonido.sh start
```

After running, open your internet browser and go to `http://127.0.0.1:10001`

Comment: yes @Ron previously(before asking this question)  I used those steps to install

Comment: what happens when you go to `http://127.0.0.1:10001`?

Comment: This Web Page Is Not available

Comment: what does `usr/local/tonido/tonido.sh start` give you?

Answer (score 0):

To install Tonido, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

For 32Bit:

```
sudo apt-get install fontconfig
wget -O tonido32.deb http://www.tonido.com/download.php?TonidoSetup_i686.deb
sudo dpkg -i tonido32.deb
sudo apt-get -f install && rm tonido32.deb
```

For 64Bit

```
cd;wget -O tonido64.sh http://drive.noobslab.com/data/apps/tonido/tonido64.sh
chmod +x tonido64.sh && ./tonido64.sh;rm tonido64.sh
```

Once installed, you can run it from Dash, by clicking on Tonido,

[image]

[image]

or open your browser, and go to: http://127.0.0.1:10001/ui/core/index.html

<sup>Source:[Noobslab](http://www.noobslab.com/2014/08/turn-your-ubuntulinux-mint-into.html)</sup>

Comment: Not working @Mitch.....I got installation completed message but Tonido not starting...

Comment: Are you getting any error messages?

Comment: i'm getting page not found error.